# Examples of topologically non trivial complete submanifolds in infinite dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

In infinite dimensional Banach spaces, many analogies of classical sets are topologically trivial ( even contractible). E.g., infinite dimensional spheres are contractible by  Y. Benyamini, Y. Sternfeld "Spheres in Infinite-Dimensional Normed Spaces are Lipschitz Contractible"

It is not difficult to construct infinite dimensional sets that are topologically non trivial. E.g., infinite dimensional torus $T^\infty = \prod^\infty S^1$ has non trivial fundamental group.

It is possible to construct embeddings of such sets into Banach spaces. E.g., one can embed the above torus into a complex $l_p(\mathbb{C})$ space. But such embeddings are usually incomplete in Banach norm. After completion, they become contractible, as is the case with the above torus.

Question: is there a systematic way to construct topologically non trivial complete sets in Banach spaces?

Q2: the same for sets that are smooth Banach manifolds?

Q3: the same two questions in the case the ambient Banach space is one of the classical sequence spaces $l_p$ or the classical function spaces $C(R^n), L_p(R^n, W^{p,q}(R^n)$.

Note: I do not know if the analogies of general linear groups are topologically trivial. Is it true that the space of linear operators between two spaces X,Y (with some norm restriction , to make it analogous to SO(n)) is topologically trivial? I think it is interesting for both classical sequence spaces and for function spaces.

For the last remark, I believe relevant discussion is provided in

Daniel Freeman, Thomas Schlumprecht, Andras Zsak  "Banach spaces for which the space of operators has 2 closed ideals"

Spiros A Argyros, Richard G Haydon "A hereditarily indecomposable L \infty-space that solves the scalar-plus-compact problem"

EDIT: It seems that one can try to make analogy of polynomially defined sets as follows. Consider a sequence space X ( any one likes - $c_0,l_p$, James, Tsirelson,...). Consider "polynomial equations"
\begin{equation}
0= p_i(x) = \sum_{j_1,...,j_n} p_{i;j_1,...,j_n} x_{j_1}...x_{j_n} 
\end{equation}
for the case when the derivative $\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial x_j}$ has infinite dimensional kernel generically. Then this defines a "algebraic Banach manifold". ( There are various subtleties involved with definition of $p_i$ as these involve tensor products). One may try to study the question on the topological type of the resulting set, for generic $p_i$. Is this done somewhere? Does it lead to something interesting?

To make analogy with algebraic geometry, it may be useful to try to define $\mathbb{P}(X)$ - corresponding projective space. To do so, one can consider limits $x_i=\xi_i/\xi_0$ $\xi_0 \rightarrow 0$. I.e. one adds codimension 1 subspaces of $X$. It seems there is no problem with this construction, is there?

Comment: There are general methods to isometrically embed metric spaces into certain Banach spaces. Would this answer your first question, or are you looking for structure than this?

Comment: What do you mean by "After completion, they become contractible, as is the case with the above torus"? If your infinite-dimensional torus is topologized as a product of circles, then it is compact. If not, then it is still true that the first embedding that I think of has non-contractible closure.

Comment: I just realized I dropped the word 'more' from my comment. I meant to say 'are you looking for more structure.'

Comment: As a side remark, note that in an infinite dimensional setting there are several different categories of continuous maps (identity+compact, Fredholm, etc) which may make a topologically trivial object non-trivial

Comment: For contractibility of the general linear group you might look at Mitiagin's classical paper

The homotopy structure of the linear group of a Banach space

https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=5403&option_lang=eng

Comment: @TomGoodwillie How do you prove noncontractibility of the torus that you are thinking about?

Comment: @PietroMajer What are the examples you have in mind?

Comment: @BillJohnson Thanks. Is there analogy of topologically nontrivial algebraic subgroups of automorphisms of  non reflexive spaces, e.g. C[0,1]?

Comment: @0x11111 In the embedding that I am thinking of, there is a projection on a 2-dimensional vector subspace such that the image of the infinite-dimensional torus is a circle. So the image of the closure is also that circle, and the closure of the torus has a circle as a retract, therefore is not contractible.

Comment: @Ox11111 For instance the unit sphere of any Banach space is not contractible by means homotopies of the form id+compact, because of the Schauder degree, just as in finite dimension.

Comment: @PietroMajer Is there something like "quantitative Frechet homotopy" theory, that addresses questions like "What is the strongest topology in which two homeomorphic sets are homotopy equivalent by a homotopy of given class?" and then develops the algebraic machinery ($\pi_nX$ etc.) for these Frechet maps?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie OK. Taking $X=T^\infty= \lim T^n$, we get $\pi(X)=Z^\omega$ ( $\omega$ - first infinite ordinal(, $H_n(X;Z)=Z^{o_n}$, where $o_n$ is the ordinal type of the set of trees of height n on $\omega$. Is there something like "Banach homology" where we allow explicitly infinite dimensional faces? ( i.e., we promote CW to "$\omega$ CW"). And where $H_nX$ are TVS.